# Running different instances on same machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm working on remote machine that I share with a coworker. We each need our own instance of the same Docker containers for development, but they're interfering with each other.

When he starts an instance, mine gets killed and vice versa, usually with a code 137. We tried editing `docker-compose.override` to look like this (this is my file):

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    container_name: ${USER}_db
    volumes:
      - /home/<him>/gces/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
  api:
    container_name: ${USER}_api
    volumes:
      - ../../gces:/var/www/gces/
      - ../../etc:/etc/gces/
      - /home/<me>/gces19/static:/srv/static/
      - /home/<me>/gces19/media:/srv/media/
      - /home/<me>/gces19/logs:/srv/logs/
    environment:
      PRODUCTION: "false"
    ports:
      - "9000:8000"
```

This looked like it was going to work. Console outputted the correct names for the instances (`<me>_api` and `<me>_db` for me, `<him>_api` and `<him>_db` when he ran it), but upon killing and restarting, we were seeing a mix of `<me>_api` and `<him>_db` regardless of which user started it up, and we still couldn't seem to run instances at the same time.

Any ideas on why this is happening and how to fix this?

Comment: try using different folders for each one of you

Comment: You should run them on different ports on host machine. One is on 9000, the other one is on 9001 for instance.